# Ratio of cases to controls in retrospective cohort study

Tags: sample-size, sample, case-control-study, case-cohort

I am conducting a retrospective cohort study in which I have 10,000 cases with exposure to X, and a very large control population (10,000,000+ subjects) without exposure.

I am taking an individual matching approach in which I match cases with controls based on multiple confounding variables (e.g. age, gender). At the moment I am matching on a 1:1 basis by sampling a random control that fulfils the matching criteria for each case (i.e. for a case with a 30-year old male, I identify all the 30-year old males in the control group, and select a random control). I would expect that a 1:1 ratio would produce the highest statistical power for my analysis. However, I have seen in other similar studies that they often use a larger ratio for cases to controls, e.g. 1:3 or 1:4.

What would be the benefit or drawbacks of using more controls, and how should I assess the optimum number of controls for my experiment?

Comment: statistical power increases along the increase of the sample size. The cost also increase along the sample size. So you need to find the balance point between statistical power and cost. If data already were collected, and no more cost is needed, then you have no reason to discard any subjects from analysis.

Comment: Thanks! But, if I am comparing two groups, isn't statistical power highest when the groups are balanced (i.e. 1:1 matching)?

Comment: Situation 1: Suppose your resource is enough to collect data from 1000 subjects. Then 500/500 split should be the best. Situation 2: Data collection is finished and you 100 subjects in one group and 900 in another group. Using all of data from 1000 subjects, instead of selecting 100 of 900, is the best.